# How to create SVGGraph with thin bars on a wide grid?

Tags: php, svggraph

I am using PHP SVGGraph to build a graph. I have a graph that currently looks like this:

[image]

What I would like to do is keep the width of the grid the same but the bars should not be so wide. I am not able to find anything in the docs on whether this can be done.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation you adjust the width of the bars using the options parameter when creating the instance:

```
// Notice the 3 argument
$graph = new SVGGraph(640, 480,array("bar_width"=>'100'));
```

Referenced from the options page (near the bottom):

http://www.goat1000.com/svggraph-bar.php#general-options